# CentOS 7.2 (Now to update)

Tags: centos, upgrade

CentOS 7 (through and including 7.1) offered the

`Applications | System Tools | Software Update`

applet. This applet allowed users to update CentOS 7.

Where is the applet in 7.2 v1511? I do not see that anymore.

Yes, I know of `yum -y update`. I executed the `yum -y update` command, which is how I got from CentOS 7 to CentOS 7 (7.2 v1511).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the Upstream(Redhat) which has been reported:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1290868

You can solve this issue by installing the `gnome-packagekit-updater` package
with this command.

```
sudo yum install gnome-packagekit-updater
```

Once this package is installed you will find the ICON where it used to be.
i.e: Applications | System Tools | Software Update

You can also start the GUI Updater from command line once it is installed by invoking this command:

```
sudo gpk-update-viewer
```

Comment: gpk-update-viewer will complain if you run it as root/with sudo, at least now.  I think it asks for a password before it starts installing.